# UWP AppBar color c#

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, win-universal-app

I'm trying myself at designing windows universal apps (windows 10), and in order that everything would look right, I wish to change application border color. I was checking forums earlier and non of the solutions seem right.

Thanks for all your time

Here is an example I have found, mint color even tho I have dark gray as my system color.

[image: Fitbit example]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [UWP Windows 10 App, TitleBar and Status bar customization](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/gianlucb/2015/10/08/uwp-windows-10-app-titlebar-and-status-bar-customization/):

```
if (ApiInformation.IsTypePresent("Windows.UI.ViewManagement.ApplicationView"))
{
    var titleBar = ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().TitleBar;
    if (titleBar != null)
    {
        titleBar.ButtonBackgroundColor = Colors.DarkBlue;
        titleBar.ButtonForegroundColor = Colors.White;
        titleBar.BackgroundColor = Colors.Blue;
        titleBar.ForegroundColor = Colors.White;
    }
}
```

Comment: I saw few solutions that look lot like yours, but this one is the only one that really works. Thank you so much